SwiftUI Pass Touches to Masked View
I have a view which I am masking with another view. The view that is being used as a mask is supposed to recognize and respond to gestures, but the view that is being masked seems to prevent those gestures from being passed through.
Simplified code:
BackgroundView()
    .mask {
        InteractiveView()
    }

BackgroundView() is a view that defines the look of the InteractiveView(), which is supposed to respond to touches. How can I prevent the BackgroundView() from blocking gestures?
I've tried solutions such as adding .allowsHitTesting(false), which fails.

And if you swap out your views, it seems like the mask shouldn't be clickable, either

Why not handle gestures on BackgroundView instead? All that matters about a mask is its alpha channel - it is not supposed to be interactive.

As Sweeper was saying in a comment, a mask is not supposed to be interactive. So an alternative approach is to show the interactive view as an overlay and use .blendMode to achieve the same masking effect.
In particular, .blendMode(.destinationOut) can be used to "erase" parts of the underlying layer. This actually gives the same effect as an inverted mask. So to use it like a normal (non-inverted mask), it can be applied twice:

Start by using .blendMode(.destinationOut) to "burn" into a solid layer of color.
Use .compositingGroup() to bind this composition together. This forms the negated mask.
Use .blendMode(.destinationOut) again, to erase the parts of the underlying layer that fall under the negated mask.
To prevent the mask from burning into lower layers, apply .compositingGroup() once again.

Here is a standalone example to illustrate it working:
struct ContentView: View {

    private var interactiveMask: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black
            InteractiveView()
                .blendMode(.destinationOut)
        }
        .compositingGroup()
        .blendMode(.destinationOut)
    }

    var body: some View {
        BackgroundView()
            .overlay { interactiveMask }
            .compositingGroup()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(.yellow)
    }
}

struct InteractiveView: View {
    @State var isLarge = false
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: isLarge ? 200 : 100)
            .padding(.leading, isLarge ? 80 : 180)
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
            .animation(.easeInOut, value: isLarge)
            .onTapGesture { isLarge.toggle() }
    }
}

struct BackgroundView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "tortoise")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .padding(20)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            .background(.green)
    }
}



Getting back to your original approach of using a .mask, there might be other ways of arranging the views that would make it possible to receive gestures in just the area of the mask. It very much depends on what content you have in your two views.
→ For example, if you are using a simple shape as a mask, you could show the same shape behind all the other content and attach gesture handlers to this version in the background. Then apply .allowsHitTesting(false) to the foreground content, to allow gestures to pass through.
So if you would like to elaborate on what content you have in your views (ideally, by providing a complete working example), it may be possible to suggest other solutions.
